# Creating objects through user generate values in form. 'addEventListener' of null

Tags: javascript, arrays, null, push, addeventlistener

I'm trying to make a form which the user generated values is sent to an Array which I will then later present on another page. The problem is that I keep getting this type error: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null. I understand that the cause of this varies which is why I would like for you to take a look at my code and see if you spot any issues with it.

I'm very new to Javascript and this is for a school assignment so I'd appreciate any information provided.

```
var persons = [];

 document.querySelector("form button").addEventListener('click', 
 function(event) {

var input = document.querySelectorAll("form input");
var newPerson = {};
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    newPerson[input[i].name] = input[i].value;
    input[i].value='';
}
persons.push(newPerson);
console.log(persons);
event.preventDefault();
```

}, false);

```
<form>
        <input type="text" name="firstName" value="" placeholder="Namn" /><br />
        <input type="text" name="lastName" value="" placeholder="Efternamn" /><br />
        <input type="text" name="phone" value="" placeholder="Telefonnummer" /><br />
        <input type="textblock" name="injuries" value="" placeholder="Skador?" /><br />
        <input type="text" name="eMail" value="" placeholder="E-mail" /><br />
        <button>Bekräfta</button>
      </form>
```

Comment: You need to import your script after your `form` or use `window.onload` event

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your JS code executes **before** page loads. So when script tries to find "form button", it doesn't exist yet.
Try to move your script **after** form element.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking. Just wanna learn new things. How do I do this without using window.onload?

Comment: It's often a good practice to put your `'<script>'` as a last element on a page, just before closing `'</body>'` tag. This way you can be sure, that all elements on a page already exist in DOM.